# Restaurant back-end systems and .Net

Tags: asp.net, api, e-commerce

How would I programmatically connect to an existing back-end system of a restaurant using say Micros POS, with a web app built with .Net and C#. Thanks.

Update: Sorry for the ambiguity but I'd like to set up an online ordering system that takes users' orders and forward to a restaurant's back-end system to be processed and printed in the kitchen for cooks to see.

There is no particular reason for choosing .Net other than the fact I'm most familiar with it. I'm open to other options.

In general I'm looking for information regarding the feasibility of this and how to go about it programmatically. How would my app send orders to the kitchen's printers? Do restaurant back-end systems allow for a .Net (or any other) app communicate with it? Do they provide an API?

Comment: Way too Localized.  Can you provide more information for why you want to do this, the reason you want to use .NET?

Comment: @Gortok, please see update in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I currently work at an ISV that does basically this with another one of the big 3 point of sale systems.

First and foremost, get the Micros environment up in a VM.

Next, most of these back office systems are running either Windows 2000 or Windows XP (depending on the age of the system), so be really careful about the version of .Net you choose.

Now, as far as architecture goes, run a service on the back office that communicates regularly with a centralized web service (the website that customers order on), once an order is made available, from there you can then insert it into <insert pos type here>.

You will also find in most instances, especially with Micros being the largest Point of Sale on the market for restaurants, they will not be very helpful with documentation and helping you out with integrating into their software.

Also, I think that My Micros (their enterprise application) already supports this type of functionality.

Comment: Is integration with such systems at all possible?

Comment: it's possible, but some are a pain in the rear. think custom data storage, huge binary files for configurations, foxpro dbf's, malformed non-standard xml streams, etc... Rule for integration, if you didn't build it, you generally have to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

Another opinion, get into [FSTech](http://www.fstec.com/home.aspx) this year and browse all the competition, there are tons for online ordering just so you can get familiar with the competitions feature sets.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to know is define what you want to do with the POS before a choice of technology, if all you want to do is show some data/reports from the POS system's work, you would need to connect to whatever back-end database the POS devices feed into.

If you need to do something else, you need to look for whatever relevant documentation.

It would help you more to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably start by determining if Micros POS has an API.  If they do, are the systems at individual restaurants even connected to the net?  Try chatting up the manager at a place that uses one of these systems, or just check the documentation on their website.

Comment: i also searching to integration on Micros API but the first requirment of them a pilot micros customer ....is there a way to implement virtual envoirment to cominicate micros system??